# Using Vuetify validation text area for manual validation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a search box for a Vuetify web application and when the user hits the search icon the form field does the typical validation rules and applies the message if it does not meet those regex specs.

I use the validated input to do a post request and see if any results return from our database. If the results do return I go to the next page, if the results fail I want to use the validation field area to say ID does not exist.

Is this possible? Does vuetify offer a way to use display a custom message in this validation area through a prop of some sort? I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it; the `Vuetify` docs have a section on input field error state: [#error](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs/#error). I put together a snippet to demonstrate the control of the error state:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      validationProp: true,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field outlined v-bind="{
                error: !validationProp,
                ...(!validationProp && { 'error-messages': ['Fatal error'] })
              }" />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-btn @click="validationProp = !validationProp">
              TOGGLE ERROR STATE
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The only catch was that if I just added the `error` attribute the control worked, but there was no message; if I also added the `error-messages`, then the control stopped working - it was stuck in a perpetual error state. Thus, I decided to add the `error-messages` conditionally:

```
...(!validationProp && { 'error-messages': ['Fatal error'] })
```

---

### EDIT

If you want to "target the `error-message`", then you just have to bind a variable to it instead of a simple string.

Based on the comment below, the snippet is edited:

```js
const DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Default error message'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      validationProp: true,
      errorMessage: DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field outlined label="Type here the error message you want" v-model="errorMessage" />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field outlined v-bind="{
                error: !validationProp,
                ...(!validationProp && { 'error-messages': [errorMessage] })
              }" />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-btn @click="validationProp = !validationProp">
              TOGGLE ERROR STATE
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for delay but can you change the error-message from the script area and modify the component directly rather than v-bind? For example, I can usually target a button in vuetify make loading true by doing  this.loading = true and that targets the loading property. Can I target the 'error-message' prop from the script area to set the message?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 added a new version of the snippet. Sorry, I assumed that it's clear that you can change the `String` to a `data attribute` easily. Now, I added an edited version, where the error message is controlled by a new input field (it can be any string you want)